# Можно ли сделать dictionary упорядоченным в Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Знаю что dict в Swift не является упорядоченной коллекцией, но необходимо сделать ее таковой. Не подскажите как?

Comment: перекинуть в массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете написать свой дженериковый dictionary, сделав его упорядоченным. Для этого, Вам надо создать массив, куда будите сохранять ключи. Обратившись по индексу в массиве, получите ключ и по ключу уже получите значение из словаря. Тут хорошая статья на эту тему: https://habrahabr.ru/post/239207/